# How to store data from a dataframe in a variable to use as a parameter in a select in cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Spark Structured Streaming application. The application receives data from kafka, and should use these values ​​as a parameter to process data from a cassandra database. My question is how do I use the data that is in the input dataframe (kafka), as "where" parameters in cassandra "select" without taking the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

This is my df input:

```
 val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options(
    Map("kafka.bootstrap.servers"-> kafka_bootstrap,
      "subscribe" -> kafka_topic,
      "startingOffsets"-> "latest",
      "fetchOffset.numRetries"-> "5",
      "kafka.group.id"-> groupId
    ))
  .load()
```

I get this error whenever I try to store the dataframe values ​​in a variable to use as a parameter.

This is the method I created to try to convert the data into variables. With that the spark give the error that I mentioned earlier:

```
def processData(messageToProcess: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

val messageDS: Dataset[Message] = messageToProcess.as[Message]

val listData: Array[Message] = messageDS.collect()

listData.foreach(x => println(x.country))

val mensagem = messageToProcess

mensagem
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to use data in Kafka to query data in Cassandra, then such operation is a typical join between two datasets - you don't need to call `.collect` to find entries, you just do the join.  And it's quite typical thing - to enrich data in Kafka with data from the external dataset, and Cassandra provides low-latency operations.

Your code could look as following (you'll need to configure so-called `DirectJoin`, see link below):

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .options(Map(...)).load()
... decode data in Kafka into columns
val cassdata = spark.read.cassandraFormat("table", "keyspace").load
val joined = df.join(cassdata, cassdata("pk") === df("some_column"))
val processed = ... process joined data

val query = processed.writeStream.....output data somewhere...start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

I have [detailed blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html) on how to perform efficient joins with data in Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggest, you have to use `writeStream.start()` in order to execute a Structured Streaming query.
You can't use the same actions you use for batch dataframes (like `.collect()`, `.show()` or `.count()`) on streaming dataframes, see the [Unsupported Operations section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations) of the Spark Structured Streaming documentation.

In your case, you are trying to use `messageDS.collect()` on a streaming dataset, which is not allowed. To achieve this goal you can use a `foreachBatch` output sink to collect the rows you need at each microbatch:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (microBatchDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    // Now microBatchDf is no longer a streaming dataframe
    // you can check with microBatchDf.isStreaming
    
    val messageDS: Dataset[Message] = microBatchDf.as[Message]

    val listData: Array[Message] = messageDS.collect()

    listData.foreach(x => println(x.country))
    
    // ...
}
```